# time data 'Timestamp' does not match format in python?

Tags: python, csv

```
> import datetime     
  import operator 
  import csv from itertools import islice
  with open( 'Path', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  output = list(islice((row[:2] for row in reader), 10))   #row[:2] for  columns and 10 for rows

#print (output)
ts = sorted([(datetime.datetime.strptime(j[0],  "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"),
j[1],j[2]) for j in [list(filter(None,k)) for k in output]], 
 key=operator.itemgetter(0)) h=[] for i in ts:
        if i[0].hour not in h:
                 print (i)
                 h.append(i[0].hour)
```

I have run this code and error is coming in Timestamp,i am not able to make out what it is,
help me out what is the error?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-84-9d6110406e31>", line 15, in <module>
    "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"),j[1],j[2]) for j in [list(filter(None,k)) for k in output]],

  File "<ipython-input-84-9d6110406e31>", line 15, in <listcomp>
    "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"),j[1],j[2]) for j in [list(filter(None,k)) for k in output]],

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))

ValueError: time data 'Timestamp' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

csv:

Timestamp,data1,data2
20-03-2017 10:00:01,50,60.5
20-03-2017 10:10:00,60,70
20-03-2017 10:40:01,75,80
20-03-2017 11:05:00,44,65
20-03-2017 11:25:01,98,42
20-03-2017 11:50:01,12,99
20-03-2017 12:00:05,13,54
20-03-2017 12:05:01,78,78
20-03-2017 12:59:01,15,89
20-03-2017 13:00:00,46,99
20-03-2017 13:23:01,44,45
20-03-2017 13:45:08,80,39

Comment: can you please share the csv

Comment: this is because your timestamp is not in  the format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'.
Can you provide one sample timestamp from your csv file?

Comment: You are likely processing the header row as well.

Comment: can u please explain with code, yes i want to header rows also but not in processing.

Answer (score 0):

You are processing the header row in your csv, you will have to skip that. Try

```
output = list(islice((row[:2] for row in list(reader)[1:]), 10))
```

The `list(reader)[1:]` will basically give all of `list(reader)` except the first row.

Comment: its giving error,
    output = list(islice((row[:2] for row in reader[1:]), 10))   #row[:2] for  columns and 10 for rows

TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. Updated the answer.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-94-36fabef79530>", line 11, in <listcomp>
    ts = sorted([(datetime.datetime.strptime(j[0],"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"),j[1],j[2]) for j in [list(filter(None,k)) for k in output]], key=operator.itemgetter(0))

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Unfortunately, your code is quite cryptic and not formatted nicely for me to comprehend it. You should try ignoring the first line, i.e. the header row from being parsed as an actual timestamp.

Comment: The `IndexError` is because you use `islice` and get rid of `data2` component of the rows, which you are trying to use in `ts`.